# Entity Framework - skip specific row?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a user tables where one user is admin. In the admin dashboard, I want to show all users escaping the admin.

I have used

```
_context.AspNetUsers.Skip(1).ToListAsync()
```

but it only skips the first row.

I also thought about `OrderBy` that specific username at first then skip, but don't know the combination.

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: What about `.Where()`?

Comment: Can you please Share a Code. I have tried "_context.AspNetUsers.OrderBy(s => s.UserName == "xxx@gmail.com").Skip(1).ToListAsync()" it show all record skiping different one. Also tried "_context.AspNetUsers.Where(s => s.UserName == "xxx@gmail.com").Skip(1).ToListAsync()" show empty Result.

Comment: Try `s.UserName != "xxx@gmail.com`. You just want to filter out one user.